# CKEditor plugin - id of current textarea

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am making plugin to CKEditor. How can I get current ID of using textarea? I need something like

```
var stringId = CKEDITOR.this.textarea.id;
```

I am using more textarea with using CKEditor on one page. Each has different ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

illogically it is method called name

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('namePlugin', {

        editor.addCommand("namePlugin", {
            exec: function () {
                alert(editor.name);
            }
        });
    }
});
```